# Find dates / hours from multiple string format in Python

Tags: python, datetime, ftplib

I need to parse some strings into datetime object in python.

Problem is: I'm fetching my strings from multiple FTP servers which are returning different strings.

MLSD and MLSN are a no go because some servers doesn't accept those.
Example:

```
lines = []
lines.append('U3SECADM       122880 23/10/20 09:22:45 *DIR       histomail/')
lines.append('drwxr-xr-x    2 1007     1000           21 Oct 20 12:46 encours')
lines.append('10-13-20  02:00AM                  264 CITDETL003_u_exp_histo_cmdb_mds_20201012180006_part1.zip')
lines.append('07-24-20  02:05AM       <DIR>          encours')
lines.append('QSYSOPR        673400 04/08/20 04:08:45 *STMF      ZZED1520200804050843173818.zip')
```

I need to strip the datetime of those strings. Is there an efficient method in python to do this?

Comment: How many ftp servers are you working with? It may be better to handle each FTP server separately assuming they each have their own outputs. So for every listed item, split it by tab or grab the date part via regex, then strptime it.

Comment: hi @Kirk at least 50 servers. That's what i'm trying to do but that's a pain to do, I thought there will be a better method

Comment: ick, that is annoying. i'm guessing there aren't that many different date formats in this thing. you could try running each through a series of regex until it parses, though that will be prone to mistakes I imagine.
If you need certainty, you could map the server to a regex that would pull the correct date. I'd imagine there are probably different date formats max.

Comment: to make it *slightly* less error-prone, you could directly map the regexes to strptime format codes and see if you can parse the output if you have a match. there might still be some corner-cases, like day-comes-first or something like that. the world would be so nice if everybody used ISO format ^^

Comment: @MrFuppes Yeah ! Thanks that's what I've done, I've created some regex, it works fine in preproduction, hopefully will works in production too !